# Error cancelling Drupal user account

Tags: drupal

When I cancel a Drupal user, I get an error from the OG Sync Bridge:

```
$backTrace = 
#0 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) 
#1 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Bridge/OG/Utils.php(116): CRM_Core_Error::fatal() 
#2 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Bridge/OG/Drupal.php(221): CRM_Bridge_OG_Utils::contactID(0) 
#3 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/civicrm_og_sync/civicrm_og_sync.module(241): CRM_Bridge_OG_Drupal::og((Array:4), "add") 
#4 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/civicrm_og_sync/civicrm_og_sync.module(68): _civicrm_og_sync_node_action(Object(stdClass)) 
#5 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/includes/module.inc(957): civicrm_og_sync_node_update(Object(stdClass)) 
#6 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/modules/node/node.module(1180): module_invoke_all("node_update", Object(stdClass)) 
#7 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/modules/node/node.admin.inc(327): node_save(Object(stdClass)) 
#8 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/modules/node/node.admin.inc(355): _node_mass_update_helper("140", (Array:1)) 
#9 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/includes/batch.inc(284): _node_mass_update_batch_process((Array:11), (Array:1), (Array:4)) 
#10 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/includes/batch.inc(161): _batch_process() 
#11 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/includes/batch.inc(80): _batch_do() 
#12 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc(2384): _batch_page() 
#13 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): system_batch_page() 
#14 /home/myuser/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() 
#15 {main}
```